# Making diagrams

Tags: diagrams

I'm interested in making a type diagram:

[image]

I have the following commands:

```
\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix@C+1em@R+1em{
\A \ar[r]^-{f} \ar[d]_-{g} & B \\
\C \ar[ur]_-{h}}    
\end{equation*}
```

Who provided me with:
[image]

What should I change to do the first diagram?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: you need 3 columns, 2 rows. `C` should be in the 2nd row, 2nd column. Then, change the arrow directions accordingly.

Comment: Why not use `tikz-cd`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If you are not insisting on `xymatrix`, you could try

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=4em]
A \arrow[rr, "f"] \arrow[rd, "g"swap]& & B\\
& C \arrow[ur, "h"swap] &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: switched to relativistic ;-) units, big thanks to @egreg.

Comment: I'm not a fan of absolute length such as 1.2cm, for these cases.

Comment: @egreg Morally I agree but do you really want to add an empty line instead?

Comment: I suggest using relative units such as `em` or `ex`.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, but isn't the relative unit convertible to cm for example in the end?

Answer (score 7):

Using the `xymatrix` package you can see an example of little guide for this package: https://www.jmilne.org/not/Mxymatrix.pdf. I have created with this package, for your request, a simple code.

Picture with equilateral triangle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C-=0.5cm{
A 
\ar@{->}[rr]^f \ar@{->}[rd]_g & & B \ar@{<-}[ld]^h\\
&C&\\
&& 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `@{->}` since it is the standard arrow style.

Comment: Why empty 3rd line in the second example?

Comment: Although it is not wrong, it is not so natural to insert an arrow from `B` to `C` with reversed tip at the starting point. It is easier to read the code if the arrow starts from `C`.

Comment: I've done a lot of rehearsals reading the guide. And to have an equilateral triangle with no errors in the compilation I have inserted the third empty line and I must necessarily use `@{->}`. I have tried to do my best, I can assure you.

Comment: I don't know the difference between `@C` and `@C-`. Also, if you use column distance equal to half centimeter, you have to be sure that the diagonal arrows also have such length. There is `@R` also.

Comment: @Sigur I've read a lot of guides to try and get an equilateral triangle. With such sincerity I no longer remember where I read it. For me you are authorized (the best are authorized) to change my code.