# writing a function between sets vertically

Tags: diagrams

Could someone help me write this picture situation [image]

I'd like to write this centrally, but I do not know where to start ...

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to write text un math mode? What about some special symbols?

Comment: I use Tex to write texts in math. But I'm no expert on more elaborate diagrams and things.

Comment: If I were to write this horizontally, I would know. But as it is in the photo I can not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0pt,nodes={inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt}]
\{\text{category of $A$--modules}\}=\, & \mathcal{C}\arrow[d] & \qquad & M \arrow[d,mapsto]\\
\{\text{category of $B$--modules}\}=\, &  \mathcal{D} & \qquad & B\otimes_A M\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With edge labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0pt,nodes={inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt}]
\{\text{category of $A$--modules}\}=\, & \mathcal{C}\arrow[d,"f" swap] & \qquad & M 
\arrow[d,mapsto,"f"]\\
\{\text{category of $B$--modules}\}=\, &  \mathcal{D} & \qquad & B\otimes_A M\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to put a letter "F" on the left side of the first arrow? As in this diagram: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460349/making-diagrams/460450#460450

Comment: @Manoel Sure, just replace \arrow[d]` by `\arrow[d,"f"]` or `\arrow[d,"f" swap]`.

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: @Manoel I added a complete example. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: With this new change, it does not work. I copy only the following part: \[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0pt,nodes={inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt}]
\{\text{category of $A$--modules}\}=\, & \mathcal{C}\arrow[d,"f" swap] & \qquad & M 
\arrow[d,mapsto,"f"]\\
\{\text{category of $B$--modules}\}=\, &  \mathcal{D} & \qquad & B\otimes_A M\\
\end{tikzcd}\]   Is that a problem?

Comment: Can you compile the full example? Do you load some babel package? If so, please add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` in the library.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. It's for my MSc dissertation!

Answer (score 3):

Another proposal using `xy` package:
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
*\txt{$\{$category of $A$--modules$\}$}&\mkern-20mu=e\ar[d]& M\ar@{|-{>}}[d]\\
*\txt{$\{$category of $B$--modules$\}$}&\mkern-20mu=\mathcal{D} & B\otimes_A M
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple `array` with two rotations:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} c c @{}}
\{\text{category of $A$-modules}\}={} & \mathcal{C} & M \\
& \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\longrightarrow$}
& \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\longmapsto$} \\
\{\text{category of $B$-modules}\}={} & \mathcal{D} & B \otimes_A M
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]